# Matplotlib 1.3.0, legend line and text do not match

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, legend

In this case the legend labels come from txt files, with a `'\n'` character at the end. Running this snippet:

```
lines = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
plt.rc('font', size=10.)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    plt.plot(range(2), line, label='line number ' + str(i) +'\n')
plt.ylim(0,4)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

in `Matplotlib 1.2.1` and `1.3.0` you will get different legends:

- **Matplotlib 1.2.1**:
  [image]
- **Matplotlib 1.3.0**
  [image]

Comment: Can you please strip this down to a minimal example and paste the code here.  Having to go through a drop box link which probably won't exist in a month is not cool.

Comment: And I suspect that your issue is with the `labelheight` and `labelspacing` parameters.

Comment: @tcaswell but why do you think it worked in 1.2.1 and not in 1.3.0? Ans about the dropbox links, I keep an exclusive folder for SO stuff when the problem requires too much code, I will start to use GitHub's Gist...

Comment: There was a bunch of work done on text layout.  I suspect that the settings you needed in 1.2.1 were work-arounds for bugs/incorrect behavior.  http://xkcd.com/1172/  I really think you can reproduce this issue with <15 lines of code, all you need is 25 plotted lines.

Comment: @tcaswell all right, I will try to reproduce the bug in a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @tcaswell I found the problem and updated the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to keep using the same algorithm in Matplotlib 1.3.0 is simple, just add a `strip()` call before passing the legend label to `plt.plot()`:

```
label_from_txt_file = label_from_txt_file.strip()
plt.plot(range(2), line, label=label_from_txt_file)
```

it will remove the `'\n'` character and avoid the line/text misalignment.